# iOS - crashing at main.m, no log, no possible breakpoint

Tags: ios, crash

I'm having this issue: my iOS application is crashing at `main.m` with the following code:

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x760b9beb8)`

The main problem is that i have absolutely no idea of where the issue lies. No log is provided. I did google a little bit a lot of the solution that adds exception breakpoint in the breakpoint navigator. It didn't help even a bit.

[image]

I've tried all of these and nothing happened. This is the log i receive in the previous UIViewController: i don't know if it might be related.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 

("NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c44974d0 UILabel:0x10ed1bf10'The numbers rule the...'.height == 40   (active)>",
"NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c4497930 UILayoutGuide:0x1c43a1960'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.bottom == UILabel:0x10ed1c1f0'\U2714 completed / file'.bottom + 13   (active)>",
"NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c4497c50 UILabel:0x10ed1bf10'The numbers rule the...'.top == UILayoutGuide:0x1c43a1960'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.top + 7   (active)>",
"NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c4497d40 V:[UILabel:0x10ed1bf10'The numbers rule the...']-(2)-[UILabel:0x10ed1c1f0'\U2714 completed / file']   (active)>",
"NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c0699e60 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' Cursos.CourseSectionCell:0x10691ba00'CourseSectionCell'.height == 56.5   (active)>",
"NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c4497a20 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-bottom' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x1c43a1960'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':Cursos.CourseSectionCell:0x10691ba00'CourseSectionCell' )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c4497980 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-top' V:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x1c43a1960'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']   (active, names: '|':Cursos.CourseSectionCell:0x10691ba00'CourseSectionCell' )>"
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c44974d0 UILabel:0x10ed1bf10'The numbers rule the...'.height == 40   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
```

As far as i know the above is simply an alert, i even tried to add the alert for `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints`, but found nothing uncommon.

I'm asking for help because i don't know any other way i could go. If my question is too shallow, feel free to ask me any details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have code that pushes or presents your next controller? What code does your next controller have? Do you have a sample project that replicates the issue? The above is just broken constraints, not a stack trace. If you can, find and upload the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to editSchenes ->Run->Diagnostics and select Zombie objects and pause on issues and now run the project. Probably you will get the issue